# Scope of extension methods

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, extension-methods

I have ran into a strange problem regarding C# extension methods

I have two projects in my Solution 
I have a database layer I call Project.Domain that contains my EF Context etc
and a WebUI layer that contains the controllers etc.

This is the simple structure of my tables

```
public class Menu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuMember> MenuMembers { get; set; }
}

public  class MenuMember
{
    public int MenuMemberId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string  ViewRoute { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}

public  class EFDbContext : DbContext
{


   public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Menu > Menus { get; set; }
   public DbSet<MenuMember> MenuMembers{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to place some extension methods on `DbSet<Pages>` .

I plan to use it in the Web UI layer . But no matter where i place the extensions methods , I can never see them when i go like repository.Pages.(Can't see the custom extension )

Please help me here

Comment: Extension method scope works exactly the same as any other scope in c# Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please add the static class that implements the extension methods.  Is it marked as `public`?